# How to turn each phone number within the $content to a telephone link?

Tags: php, html, content, the-content

I am working on a webpage that lists all the [access numbers](http://helpfulpost.com/boss-revolution-access-number/) our customers ask for.

What I am trying to do is turn all the text phone numbers into telephone links through a php function rather than manually add the html markup to every number.

I was hoping that I can do it myself but, damn, what a disappointment!

This is the current markup for each phone number:

```
<div name="Missouri" style="display:none" class="zebra1"> (573) 213 2134</div>
```

What I am trying to do is turn the above markup like so:

```
<div name="Missouri" style="display:none" class="zebra1"> <a href="tel:(573) 213 2134">(573) 213 2134</a></div>
```

Note: This phone number is for the state of Missouri; however there are several phone numbers for each state.

I have only got started and I'm stuck:

```
function accessnumber($content) {

}
add_filter('the_content', 'accessnumber',60);
```

There are over 200 numbers so doing it manually is currently not an option for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using following custom code.

```
function accessnumber( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace( '#(<div[^>]*class=\"zebra[^>]*\">)(.*?)(</div>)#is', '$1<a href="tel:$2">$2</a>$3', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'accessnumber', 60 );
```

Comment: Very impressive! However, It didn't cross my mind to include that not all the name tags within the divs equal Missouri. Each state has several access numbers.

Comment: It doesn't, some numbers are not showing up. I'm trying to tweak your code but I am not having any luck

Comment: It is working fine for me. Could you please share me the phone number and markup where it is not working?

Comment: this is the link on code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmxVJy

Comment: I tested your code on localhost machine

Comment: I changed above code so try using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58651/discussion-between-vinod-dalvi-and-fabian-amran).

Comment: you are the man. It works like a charm! Thanks for showing me that it can be done. Really appreciate it. Now I am going to exam your code and try to figure out how the hell the variable $1, $2, and $3 have appropriate information stored in them :)